# Ruby: creating a sandboxed eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eval, sandbox

My Rails app has complicated rules about when a bit of content should be displayed on a page or not.  I've decided to implement this by writing predicates (simple 'yes/no' functions) in Ruby and storing them in the db for subsequent eval'ing.  It it pretty straightforward.

My main concern is security: if a malicious somebody figures out how to write to the db, they could stick arbitrary Ruby code in the db and then '*all your base are belong to us*'.

So is it possible to create an 'sandboxed' eval, for example, which has all IO operations removed?

Comment: Some good responses here, which have led to a [follow on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100616/ruby-looking-for-ruby-embeddable-interpreter-or-scripting-language)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run untrusted Ruby code inside a safe sandbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169303/how-to-run-untrusted-ruby-code-inside-a-safe-sandbox)

Comment: Agree that this smells like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169303/how-to-run-untrusted-ruby-code-inside-a-safe-sandbox.  FWIW, the follow on question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100616/ruby-looking-for-ruby-embeddable-interpreter-or-scripting-language) is probably the *real* answer, in other words, use a dedicated DSL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check the 'taint' method and related stuff. This is a good reference:

http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html

Despite that, I can't advise you enough against storing code and evaluating it, it's a security risk that should be avoided and most times there's a simpler way of solving your problems.

If you need to evaluate complex rules and predicates I'd recommend a rule engine to create a nice DSL. Haven't used one in ruby but this one looks good to me:

http://treetop.rubyforge.org/index.html

Cheers

Comment: (and all): I agree that storing eval'd code in a db is asking for trouble.  In this case, I need to *dynamically* add and remove arbitrarily complex predicates, where one such predicate might be 'IF the house is greater than 2000 ft squared AND in zip code 90210 AND the registered owner has three cars AND doesn't like purple hats THEN true'.  I could hardwire the predicates into a class, but then i'd be doing continual git pushes.  Ultimately, despite the risks, this seems better in the db.  Let me know if you can think of a better way!

Comment: @fearless_fool hm ok. I'll have to give this some thought. I hope you built in enough error checking in case there's something like a syntax error.

Comment: @fearless_fool, edited the question with what I think is a better solution to `eval`

Comment: My first reaction was "why write another DSL if Ruby touts itself as a DSL tool?'  But the more I think about it, the more I see the wisdom of using Treetop or something like it: it gives you total control of the sandbox.

Comment: okay, you get the checkmark!  I found [James Coglan's stickup](https://github.com/jcoglan/stickup), a tiny scheme interpreter written using Treetop, and it only took a couple of hours to learn it, extend it and integrate it into my app.  And yes, this is a safer approach than twiddling $SAFE.  Thanks for the nudge!

Answer (score 6):

you can do that with a sandboxing gem, https://github.com/tario/shikashi, which allows you to whitelist methods.
credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8704768/188355

Comment: technically: more like 2 commits in the last two years.  
but it's a small enough gem that a person can support himself if he needs to.

Comment: Yes, I used it, it seems to be ok. But I'm searching for a better solution right now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267847/user-editable-html-xss-protection-tumblr-like

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're on at least ruby 1.8, you can run a proc at a different safe level.

```
def my_unsafe_function
  # possible unsafe stuff
end

proc {
  $SAFE = 4  # change level only inside this proc
  my_unsafe_function
}.call
```

However, you should rethink whether you really need to store ruby code in the DB. Are users of the app going to be modifying this stored code, and why? If they aren't, why not put the code in the app's files instead? I don't know your setup, but it should be possible to move the logic out of the DB.

Comment: see my reply to @Pablo above.  The predicates change frequently based on external factors.  We *could* bake them into .rb files, but we'd be doing a lot of git pushes.  FWIW, it's the administrators, not the users, will be modifying the stored code.

Comment: PS: I forgot to mention: that's a nice construct for running a function at $SAFE = 4.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all Ruby implementations fully implement safe (for example, JRuby doesn't treat it as a high priority), or implement it perfectly ([MRI had a bug](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/02/18/exception-methods-can-bypass-safe/)).

Comment: This [doesn't work](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/NEWS.html#label-Built-in+global+variables+compatibility+issues) in MRI 2.1.0:  `ArgumentError: $SAFE=4 is obsolete
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove some methods from your object, you can check this: 
[remove_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/remove_method)
or [undef_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/undef_method)