# Ruby: looking for ruby-embeddable interpreter or scripting language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interpreter, dsl

In response to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074915/ruby-creating-a-sandboxed-eval), [@Pablo Fernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7595/pablo-fernandez)  suggested I implement a simple interpreter using [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/index.html) to embed in my RoR application.  It looks like a good approach.

But I can't help but wonder: hasn't anyone written a toy interpreter to embed in a Ruby app?  I don't need any I/O functions -- in fact, I specifically don't *want* any I/O functions.  (If you're wondering why I want an interpreter inside of Ruby, please refer to the original post!)

Thanks.

Comment: To answer my own question: a stripped down version of scheme written in Treetop would suit my needs, so [James Coglan's](https://github.com/jcoglan) elegant and tiny [stickup](https://github.com/jcoglan/stickup) looks like an excellent starting point.

Comment: It'd be a pain and overkill, but I'd bet you could interface Ruby with Lua easier than writing your own interpreter.. Also, are you tied only to Ruby interpreter, or are you open to other solutions with an interface with Ruby? (for instance, an interpreter implemented in .Net or whatever)

Comment: @Earlz: Within the last 45 minutes, I downloaded and tweaked stickup to do everything I needed (adding floats and integrating with my Ruby environment) -- it turned out to be refreshingly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I ended up tweaking a version of [stickup](https://github.com/jcoglan/stickup) to use as a embeddable interpreter.  The process was fast and easy and serves my needs well.  (And besides, I used to work for a Common Lisp company, so it was an excuse to re-live the joys of s-expressions.)