# Preventing filesystem access and other destructive actions

Tags: ruby, sandbox

I would like to create a small Rails application that would allow users to give a few snippets of code to benchmark in multiple implementations and versions of Ruby. I am capable of creating the application, I am just afraid of users mucking around in the filesystem or doing other destructive actions. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: [`$SAFE`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html#S1) might do the trick.

Comment: The trick? That's exactly what I needed =p Thanks! Create a response so I can select as the answer for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`$SAFE`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html#S1):

> The variable `$SAFE` determines Ruby's level of paranoia.

The various "safety levels" are noted at the link, there's also some examples (which still work) of using a thread, `$SAFE`, and [`load`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001417) to wrap untrusted code. [$SAFE on ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169303/safe-on-ruby) might be worth a look as well.