# Sandboxed plugins for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins

I'm looking to create a web app that will run plugins from untrusted sources (i.e. community submissions). So I need to lock down those plugins into a sandbox where only certain access is allowed (can't write to disk, etc.). Ideally, the plugin would only be able to use certain approved packages and APIs.

Is this possible in Ruby on Rails? If so, can you point me toward a package or documentation that will get me started?

Comment: Take a look at the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169303/safe-on-ruby

Answer (score 1):

Set $SAFE to 4, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I did not know about this functionality.  Can you provide some more detail on how I would set up a "plugin" as safe but still allow my main code to execute in "god mode"?  Also, how to I whitelist certain functionality for the sandboxed code, for example to allow the plugin to use an API that I provide?

Comment: FYI just setting `$SAFE = 4` is not enough to keep harmful/hostile code at bay (e.g. DoS)