# Convert String to Hash in includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a query such as:

```
users = User.includes(:address, friends: [:address, :followers])
```

However, the section in the *includes* part will be a string i.e. `":address, friends: [:address, :followers]"` (it's coming from a Rails app to a Rails API). Is it possible to convert this string into the Hash needed? eval() doesn't work.

Edit (for YAML):

```
def show
  str = "address, { friends: [ address, followers ] }"
  args = YAML.load("[ #{str} ]")
  user = User.includes(*args).find(params[:id])
  render :template => 'users/show'
end
```

Comment: `eval` would work fine if you surrounded it with square brackets—but it would be very foolish to use `eval` on user input.

Comment: `eval("User.includes(#{string})")` would also work, but as @Jordan said, you are doing it wrong. You should receive a list of includes in some internal format from the app and _safely build the list of includes_ on it.

Comment: Evaluation of "user submited code" is very dangerous task. At last consider sandboxing place where this code gets executed. [Read this post about $SAFE in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169303/how-to-run-untrusted-ruby-code-inside-a-safe-sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting your user input Ruby code, use YAML, which is nearly as succinct and safe to parse:

```
str = "address, { friends: [ address, followers ] }"
args = YAML.load("[ #{str} ]")
user = User.includes(*args)
```

Comment: @Shannon I need more information. What does your exact code look like? What is the exact value of the string? What is the error message in its entirety? It works fine for me: https://repl.it/FKpa